# playframework scala slick how many attributes are allowed

Tags: scala, playframework

In my Playframework scala application I have the following model:

```
case class ProcessTemplatesModel(
                                  id: Option[Int] = None,
                                  title: String,
                                  version: String,
                                  createdat: Option[String],
                                  updatedat: Option[String],
                                  deadline: Option[Date],
                                  status: Option[String],
                                  comment: Option[String],
                                  checked: Option[Boolean],
                                  checkedat: Option[Date],
                                  approved: Option[Boolean],
                                  approvedat: Option[Date],
                                  deleted: Boolean,
                                  approveprocess: Int,
                                  trainingsprocess: Option[Int],
                                  previousVersion: Option[Int],
                                  originTemplate: Option[Int],
                                  client: Int,
                                  approveProcessInstance: Option[Int],
                                  responsible: Option[Seq[UserModel]],
                                  accountable: Option[Seq[UserModel]],
                                  consulted: Option[Seq[UserModel]],
                                  informed: Option[Seq[UserModel]])

object ProcessTemplatesModel {
  implicit val processFormat = Json.format[ProcessTemplatesModel]
}
```

Today I added the `approveProcessInstance: Option[Int],`

Now I got this error while it compiles: `No unapply or unapplySeq function found` ... on this line: `implicit val processFormat = Json.format[ProcessTemplatesModel]`

Why does this fail in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

22 values is a max in play JSON, you can use 3rd party libraries to increase the number.

Here the issue thread in the Play source:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3174

One of the possible solution:
https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions

**Example from my `build.sbt`**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  filters,
  ws,
  // More than 22 fields in Json
  "ai.x" %% "play-json-extensions" % "0.8.0"
)
```

For Play 2.6 you need to use version 10:

```
"ai.x" %% "play-json-extensions" % "0.10.0"
```

Then, in the file with JSON:

```
import ai.x.play.json.Jsonx

implicit val processFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[ProcessTemplatesModel]
```

More details: https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions#create-explicit-formatter

Comment: damn ... and I have 23 now ... do you have an example for me which I can use?

Comment: is it just importing the lib or do I have to change something more?

Comment: yes, like here: 

https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions#create-explicit-formatter

Comment: in some cases it's enough just implicit import (see the answer) in other you need to use `Jsonx`. Please look at the library documentation. In your case it can be like: `implicit val processFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[ProcessTemplatesModel]`

Comment: do I have to replace play JSON every where in each controller an do so on?

Comment: solved! Thanks .. how many values are allowed now? X or is there limit bevor X ?^^

Comment: I do not know, there is no number in the documentation. I never used bigger than 30-40. I do not think it is a good solution to do so big one-level objects, so I always do subclasses and never have more than 10-20 in one. The reason I need this "more than 22" solution to interact with 3rd party JSON API, some of them can have more than 22 fields.

Comment: yes of course its not useful. just wanted to know. Can you maybe give me an example of subclasses?

Comment: For example, you can extract "version", "createdat",  "updatedat" in to "meta" subclass, so you will have one field on the place of 3. 22 is the limit for the "plain" object, so if you have 40 fields, then you can create two classes with 20 field in each and one with 2 fields that have types of that with 20: "myobject.first.f1 ... myobject.first.f20, myobject.second.f1 ... myobject.second.f20"

Comment: (not about the question but still) maybe you can reduce the fields "checked" and "checkedat" (and similar) to one field. "checkedat" is optional, so if it have some value than "checked" is true otherwise "false". "checked" always can be calculated from "checkedat" so it redundant in serialization (like JSON, actually, is).  I do not know your requirements so this is only an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

One other idea would be to decompose the model into fine grained models and have a composition of it. This way, you do not have to import yet another library!

Comment: when I do that how does it work and which problems do I get with existing code?